# Is there a wifi-menu (from Arch Linux) equivalent in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation

I really like `wifi-menu`, the command line wizard for setting up profiles for wireless interfaces on Arch Linux.

[image]

It's very convenient and easy to use.

I can't find the same software in Debian derivatives.

Is there a terminal-based wireless interface setup wizard for Ubuntu?

Comment: IIRC It's provided by the package `netctl` in Arch repos, but AFAIK even if you could install it on Ubuntu it would be difficult to configure the system to use it, because it conflicts with NetworkManager. I can't think of anything similar to wifi-menu (which is indeed rather nice), but NetworkManager's pretty cli interface `nmcli` *might* have some of the functionality you want (maybe you've already tested it and found it wanting...)

Comment: folks from reddit talk about `nmtui` should check it

Answer (score 7):

A good equivalent in Debian/Ubuntu is `wicd-curses`.

Just remember to input the WPA password BEFORE trying to connect to the network:

1. Highlight the WiFi you want to connect to
2. Press `RightArrow` to configure the network
3. The last option is the password. Input the password
4. Save
5. Press `ENTER` on the network list to connect automagically.

You can even configure it to connect automatically next time it sees the network.

[image: WICD Screenshot]

Sources and more info: [Guide to WICD](http://www.raspyfi.com/wi-fi-on-raspberry-pi-a-simple-guide/)

Comment: Does this also install `wicd`? Because `wicd` will remove `network manager`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install netctl -y

$ sudo wifi -menu -y
```

If you ask me, a lot of these extravagant processes put in place other than my above are simply uncalled for.

Netplan has the most stringent punctuation, and I advise new users against it. But only if they if have an Ethernet handy in order to install netctl.

Comment: You write `wifi -menu` but I think you mean `wifi-menu`. And that command does not have a `-y` flag.